# How to sample dataframe where sum matches partially with column sum

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe:

```
  id     sum
  123    12
  234    12
  345    50
  124    23
  111    20
  116    20
```

Now I want to subset dataframe where `sum` matches 100 or near to 100

desired dataframe would be

```
  id     sum
  123    12
  234    12
  345    50
  124    23
```

Sum is 97 which is near to 100

How can I do it in R without using for loop?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't see which sum is 97. Besides, would `id` duplicate in this data frame?

Comment: Are you asking "how to sample" or "how to subset"?

Comment: How to subset ? Starting from the first row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
id = c(123,234,345,124,111,116)
sum = c(12,12,50,23,20,20)
df = data.frame("id" = id, "sum"=sum)
df[cumsum(df$sum) <110,]

#  id sum
#1 123  12
#2 234  12
#3 345  50
#4 124  23
```

Comment: Why are you using `110` and not `100`?

Comment: `cumsum(df$sum) >= 100` can be closer to 100 than `cumsum(df$sum) < 100`

Comment: @PoGibas, just because Jaap ask to be "100 or near to 100"... but yes it's improvable

Answer (score 3):

To get the first rows with the cumsum the closest to 100 :

```
df[1L:which.min(abs(cumsum(df$sum) - 100)), ]
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, but you're looking what's "closest" (`which.min`) to 100, but not "close".  What if closest value is `150`?

Comment: Yes you are right ! I'm not sure what should happen if there is no value "close" to 100 (and how to define close)